# Probability of wrong decision in randomized hypotheses testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, information-theory

Consider a hypotheses testing problem: an i.i.d. sequence $\mathbf{x} \in \mathrm{X}^k$ is generated according to either $P(x)$ or $Q(x)$. After observing it, we want to decide which distribution has generated the sequence.

In a *non-randomized* test, one accepts $P$ if $\mathbf{x}$ belongs to some set $\mathrm{A}\subset\mathrm{X}^k$. In this case, the probability of wrong decision when $Q$ is the true probability is given by $Q^k(\mathrm{A})$.

In a *randomized* test, on the other hand, one accepts the hypotheses $P$ with a probability $\pi(\mathbf{x})$.

**Question:** In the randomized case, how to write the probability of wrong decision when $Q$ is true?

*Context:* I am trying to solve Problem 1.3. from Csiszár and Körner's Information Theory.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Something that might help: try to understand step-by-step the logic for deriving that the probability of wrong decision when $Q$ is the true probability is $Q^k(A)$. Where in the logic do you use the fact that the test is non-randomized? That might give some hints for where you would modify the derivation of the non-randomized case to accomodate the randomized case.

Comment: In the non-randomized case, writing this seems pretty straightforward. Loosely denoting $H \in \{ P, Q \}$ the correct hypothesis and $\hat{H}$ our guess, the probability of wrong decision is simply $\Pr[\hat{H}=P \mid H=Q] = \Pr[\mathbf{x} \in \mathrm{A} \mid H = Q] = Q^k(A)$, i.e., the $Q$-probability (as $Q$ is true) that $\mathbf{x} \in \mathrm{A}$ (the rule for deciding for $P$). The fact that the test is non-randomized is used in the very first step. In the randomized test there doesn't seem to be such a rule; I wish I could replace $\mathbf{x} \in \mathrm{A}$ by something else.

Comment: I'm not sure what's mean by a "randomized test". Is this at all related to Fisher's randomization test?

Comment: @AdamO Randomized tests are employed theoretically and sometimes in practice to create a test with *exactly* the intended size when the distribution of the statistic is discrete.  Ordinarily a test assigns a decision (such as "accept" or "reject") to every possible value of the statistic.  A randomized test might require you to flip a biased coin (whose bias is determined by the test statistic) to make the decision.  This is a basic construct in the decision-theoretic foundations of hypothesis testing, so you can read about it in any advanced textbook.

Comment: @whuber thanks, I've heard of these "tie breaking" procedures before but never knew it by name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to think about the identity
$$Pr[\hat H = P| H = Q] = \mathrm{Pr}[\mathbf x\in A | H = Q]$$
is to use the law of total probability to write that $$\mathrm{Pr}[\hat H = P | H = Q] = \mathbb E[\mathrm{Pr}[\hat H = P | H = Q, \mathbf X] | H = Q].$$ The fact that a test is non-randomized then implies that $\mathrm{Pr}[\hat H = P | H = Q, \mathbf X]$ is either 0 or 1, and in particular, is 1 if and only if $\mathbf X\in A$. In this case, you can simplify the RHS further to
$$\mathbb E[\mathrm{Pr}[\hat H = P | H = Q, \mathbf X] | H = Q] = \mathbb E[1\{\mathbf X\in A\} | H = Q] = \mathrm{Pr}[\mathbf X \in A | H=Q] = Q^k(A).$$
With a randomized test, the only subtlety is that that inner conditional can be something other than 0 or 1. In that case, we have
$$\mathbb E[\mathrm{Pr}[\hat H = p| H=Q,\mathbf X]] = \mathbb E_{Q^k}[\pi(\mathbf X)]$$
I do not know of any way to further simplify this expression *without additional assumptions* about, e.g., what $\pi$ looks like or what $A$ looks like.